# create trigger when I use area code outside of a specific state

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a Trigger that lets me know when I enter a phone number outside of CA. This is what I have so far, but I think this will always generate a trigger message each time a phone number is entered regardless of the area code/state.

Not sure if I need to specify more in my customerphone table or not, if so what am I missing if anything?

Here is my code I have thus far...

```
Create Trigger NumberOutsideCA
On CustomerPhone
After Insert, Update as
    Print 'Phone Number is Outside CA'
Return
```

Comment: Using a print statement in a trigger is helpful for debugging but pretty useless after that unless your users are using SSMS to insert their data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the magic table "inserted" to check whether the phone number is outside CA and can log that record some where.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumberOutsideCA ON CustomerPhone
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Here i have user CustomerPhoneLog table to log the record. You can make your own table
    INSERT INTO CustomerPhoneLog (CustomerPhoneID,Message)
    SELECT CustomerPhoneID
        , 'This phone number doest not belongs to CA State'
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE STATE != 'CA' -- Here you have to user proper condition to check the phone number outside CA
END
```

Comment: Why the temp table here? It is not needed. And certainly no need to check if the state is not CA again since there couldn't possibly be any values in there that do equal CA.

Comment: Yes we can avoid the use of temp table. I have added state filtration just for example as "Moroni Besendorfer" wants to know the number which is out side the CA. @SeanLange

Comment: You could remove the EXISTS check here too. No point in checking first and then inserting them. Just insert them. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed. Updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you. I will work on that. I don't have a State in my phone table, it just have phoneNumberID as the primary Key and then CustomerID as the foreign. I may see if it lets me pull it in by using a wild card after the area codes. This give me a new direction.